# Recursive template for pointer generation

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I want to create a template which takes a type T and a parameter N as arguments and 'gives' a pointer of Nth grade for T(eg. if T is `int` and N is `2` it should give `int**`)

My code so far is:

```
template<class T,int N>
struct ptr
{
  typedef ptr<T*,N-1>::t t;
};

template<class T>
struct ptr<T,0>
{
  typedef T t;
};

int main()
{
  ptr<int,3>::t a; //a should be int***
}
```

But it gives me this compiler error:

`source.cpp:6:11: error: need 'typename' before 'ptr<T*, (N - 1)>::t' because 'ptr<T*, (N - 1)>' is a dependent scope`

What does this mean and how can it be fixed(if its possible in C++)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that `ptr<T*, (N - 1)>::t` is a *dependent name*.

The meaning of `t` used in a template definition depends upon the template parameters, so the compiler cannot automatically determine that `t` is a type and not an object.

To correct the error, you have to give the compiler a hint, i.e. to do literally what the message suggests: prefix it with `typename`

```
typedef typename ptr<T*,N-1>::t t;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T,int N>
struct ptr
{
  typedef typename ptr<T*,N-1>::t t;
};

template<class T>
struct ptr<T,0>
{
  typedef T t;
};

int main()
{
  ptr<int,3>::t a; //a should be int***
}
```

Compiler tells that `t` is `dependent name`, so use `typename` before `ptr<T*, (N - 1)>::t`